# Vuetify and vue.js, what is the best way to change the size of actual button icon?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

This is the button that I am trying to change, as you can see when I put the "large" attribute on my `v-btn` element below, the padding around it grows but the button icon stays the same size

[image: button I am trying to change]

What is the best way to change the size of the actual button icon inside of the circle of padding? I couldn't find much on vuetify's docs for this https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: why aren't you setting the icon size the way you want, if you have a `large` button, make the icon `large` too or `x-large`.

Comment: i put the large prop on my icon nothing happened
`<i large class="material-icons">helpl</i>`

Comment: Oh, I use `v-icon` that has that property... `<v-icon x-large>mdi-cancel</v-icon>` Sorry, was assuming you were using it.

Comment: It was wrong of me to assume ;) But here we can see that adding the relevant code in question is very important ;)

Comment: you're right! i ended up just adding a class to my `i` element to change font-size, if anyone has a better solution let me know